# Selecting next row(a whole row, not cell) in datagridview after row deletion

Tags: c#, winforms, events, datagridview, row

I have a problem with deletion of rows from datagridview. I want the next row to be selected fully after the previous one was deleted, so I can delete multiple rows in a row by pressing "Delete" button. The problem is that after row deletion, I get the first cell of the next row selected, so when I press "Delete" I just erase the content of that cell and I have to click of the row header to be able to remove in with "Delete" button click.

Any ideas/help about how the about can be fixed will be highly appreciated.

Thanks a lot.

Regards,
Igor

UPDATE:SelectionMode is already set to FullRowSelect mode. I forgot to mention that I have textboxes embedded into the grid cells, and when I delete a row, the textbox in the first cell of the next row  gets selected and therefore I can't delete this row by pressing Delete button: I need to select the whole row again by pressing the row header.

Answer (score 0):

What if you change the SelectionMode to "FullRowSelect" in DataGridView properties?

Comment: SelectionMode is already set to FullRowSelect mode. I forgot to mention that I have textboxes embedded into the grid cells, and when I delete a row, the textbox in the first cell of the next row gets selected and therefore I can't delete this row by pressing Delete button: I need to select the whole row again by pressing the row header.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `SelectionMode` property of the `DataGridView` either from the Properties window or from the code like this,

```
dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
```

This should solve your issue.

Comment: SelectionMode is already set to FullRowSelect mode. I forgot to mention that I have textboxes embedded into the grid cells, and when I delete a row, the textbox in the first cell of the next row gets selected and therefore I can't delete this row by pressing Delete button: I need to select the whole row again by pressing the row header.

Comment: What do you mean by embedded Textboxes? Are you hosting Textbox controls inside cells?

Comment: Yes, I'm using DataGridViewTextBoxColumn class.